# How to put number of chapter and section in the bookmarks of the .pdf

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I would like the number of the chapters and sections to appear also on the index of the .pdf document. That is, on the left of this image:

[image]

I assume it can be done with the hyperref package, but I don't find the option.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,DIV=10]{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %to include more or less information in the table of contents
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} %para evitar cortes de palabras debido a falta de espacio en la línea
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{color, xcolor, soulutf8} %to highlight with \hl{}
    \usepackage{datetime}
    \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{
            breaklinks=false,
            linktocpage=false,
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            citecolor=black,
            urlcolor=blue,
            menucolor=black}
    \usepackage{cancel}
    \usepackage{slashed} 
    \usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %para escribir cosas en cajitas
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage{graphicx} %necessary for images
    \usepackage{subcaption} %necessary for images
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[font={small}]{caption} %to make the text in captions of images smaller
    \numberwithin{equation}{section} %to number the equations by sections
    \usepackage{enumerate} %to make lists with letters
    \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
    \usepackage[    protrusion=true,
        expansion=true,
        final,
        babel
            ]{microtype} %para arreglar que las palabras se salgan del margen de la derecha

\chapter{Quarks and color}
La dinámica de la interacción fuerte tiene que ser una dinámica de color, pero es una dinámica sutil porque no lo vemos. Color y confinamiento van a ser dos conceptos bastante ligados.

Implementar esto en una teoría cuántica de campos es difícil. Ahora veremos por qué la libertad asintótica es una propiedad de la interacción fuerte. Lo descubrimos estudiando interacciones a muy alta energía de electrones con protones.

\section{Deep inelastic scattering: asymptotic freedom}

Cogemos un haz de electrones de muy alta energía y lo hacemos colisionar con protones, y en primera aproximación nos olvidamos de la interacción fuerte. Si la energía es suficientemente alta, la longitud de onda de esos fotones será más pequeña que el tamaño del protón y será capaz de resolver los detalles de lo que hay dentro del protón, que es un espacio vacío con puntitos, que son los que hacen las colisiones duras. Lo que tenemos que describir es, si ahí hay un quark de espín 1/2, si tenemos una interacción electromagnética entre dos fermiones de Dirac. Esto es un diagrama de orden árbol en electrodinámica.

Llamaremos $q$ al momento transferido al fotón, y definimos $Q^2 = -q^2$ para pasar a una variable positiva. También introducimos una nueva variable:

  \begin{equation}
\nu \equiv \frac{P \cdot q}{M_p} = E_e - E'_e = \frac{Q^2+P_X^2-M_p^2}{2M_p}
\end{equation}
donde $q^\mu = k_e^\mu - k_e^{'\mu} = P_X^\mu - P^\mu$, y

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would help a lot if you included the preamble of your document and a sample document (a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) so that we can see how your document is organised and which packages you use.

Comment: `Index` is misleading. You mean the `bookmarks` or `pdf outline` and you need `hyperref`, or better, the `bookmark` package for this. Usually the bookmarks are added automatically, until some weird setting prevents this, e.g. `\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}`

Comment: There is  `\begin{document}` missing in the 'MWE' ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having bookmarks numbered, the `bookmarksnumbered` option is to be given to `hyperref` or in `\hypersetup`.

`hyperref` should be loaded last in 99.9% of all cases, only a few exceptions should be loaded **after** `hyperref`.

In case the `bookmark` package is applied, the relevant option is `numbered`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,DIV=10]{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %to include more or less information in the table of contents
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} %para evitar cortes de palabras debido a falta de espacio en la línea
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
    \usepackage{color, xcolor, soulutf8} %to highlight with \hl{}
    \usepackage{datetime}
    \usepackage{cancel}
    \usepackage{slashed} 
    \usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %para escribir cosas en cajitas
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage{graphicx} %necessary for images
    \usepackage{subcaption} %necessary for images
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[font={small}]{caption} %to make the text in captions of images smaller
    \numberwithin{equation}{section} %to number the equations by sections
    \usepackage{enumerate} %to make lists with letters
    \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
    \usepackage[    protrusion=true,
        expansion=true,
        final,
        babel
            ]{microtype} %para arreglar que las palabras se salgan del margen de la derecha

    \usepackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{
          bookmarksnumbered,
            breaklinks=false,
            linktocpage=false,
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            citecolor=black,
            urlcolor=blue,
            menucolor=black}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Quarks and color}
La dinámica de la interacción fuerte tiene que ser una dinámica de color, pero es una dinámica sutil porque no lo vemos. Color y confinamiento van a ser dos conceptos bastante ligados.

Implementar esto en una teoría cuántica de campos es difícil. Ahora veremos por qué la libertad asintótica es una propiedad de la interacción fuerte. Lo descubrimos estudiando interacciones a muy alta energía de electrones con protones.

\section{Deep inelastic scattering: asymptotic freedom}

Cogemos un haz de electrones de muy alta energía y lo hacemos colisionar con protones, y en primera aproximación nos olvidamos de la interacción fuerte. Si la energía es suficientemente alta, la longitud de onda de esos fotones será más pequeña que el tamaño del protón y será capaz de resolver los detalles de lo que hay dentro del protón, que es un espacio vacío con puntitos, que son los que hacen las colisiones duras. Lo que tenemos que describir es, si ahí hay un quark de espín 1/2, si tenemos una interacción electromagnética entre dos fermiones de Dirac. Esto es un diagrama de orden árbol en electrodinámica.

Llamaremos $q$ al momento transferido al fotón, y definimos $Q^2 = -q^2$ para pasar a una variable positiva. También introducimos una nueva variable:

  \begin{equation}
\nu \equiv \frac{P \cdot q}{M_p} = E_e - E'_e = \frac{Q^2+P_X^2-M_p^2}{2M_p}
\end{equation}
donde $q^\mu = k_e^\mu - k_e^{'\mu} = P_X^\mu - P^\mu$, y

\end{document}
```

[image]